# Results on derivatives with respect to the parameter of Modified Bessel Function

Tags: special-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Derivate Bessel Function with respect to order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4019/derivate-bessel-function-with-respect-to-order)

Dear colleagues, 
I have a question about the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $I_\nu(x)$ and $K_\nu(x)$.  I want to know if there is any result on the derivatives with respect to the parameter $\nu$ of $I_\nu(x)$ and $K_\nu(x)$. That is I want to know where I can find some reference about $\partial_\nu I_\nu (x)$ and $\partial_\nu K_\nu (x)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your question was answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4019/derivate-bessel-function-with-respect-to-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, for example, [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.38). As noted in this link, further details can be found in [this paper](http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~db=all?content=10.1080/10652460410001727572).

Comment: Note that you can find more information by pressing the $i$ symbols on the left.